# Upstart: Repeat a task as a service

Tags: upstart

I have a number of services in init.d that are simple one-line commands wrapped in a script that repeats every few seconds.  The template for them looks like this:

e.g.

```
#!/bin/sh
autostart() {
    while true
    do
            $@ ; sleep 20
    done
}

case "$1" in
    start)
            echo " started"
            autostart /path/to/checksomethingquickly
            ;;
    stop)
            me=`basename $0`
            killall checksomethingquickly $me
            ;;
esac

## End of File
```

The crux of this "service" is to call checksomethingquickly every 20 seconds.  (Hence it's too quick for cron.)  We want it to start when told to, and kill any/all running instances when it's told to stop.

It looks to me like it could be a "Task Job" in upstart but I'm unclear on how to ensure that the Task is repeated indefinitely and separated by 20 seconds.  Ensuring it's serialised would be a nice improvement, too.

Is this the kind of script that can be turned into a upstart script?  If so, how?